# Angular2 - How to exclude fields from form

Tags: angular

I have a data table with filters, but it also has a row for insertion.
Since the form is wrapped around the whole table, filters are also a part of my form.

Is there any way to exclude the filters on submit?

**Edit:** Think I found the answer - inputs that don't have `ngControl` bound to them are not a part of the form

Comment: Wrap the form element only around fields that should be contained in the submit?

Comment: It is a html mistake to write a form inside a table. It should always be wrapped around